# ステータスバーを残して、ナビゲーションバーを消す方法

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2

iOSで、facebookのようにスクロールに追従して、ステータスバーを残して、ナビゲーションバーを消す方法ってどうやるのでしょうか。

できればライブラリを使わないで実現したいのですが、（ossライブラリを極力使わない方針なので）実現方法教えてください。

普通に       
 self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
すると、両方消えます。

Answer (score 1):

一番簡単にやるのであれば、`UINavigationController`の`hidesBarsOnSwipe`を`true`にすればできます。

```
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
```

[リファレンス](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/hidesBarsOnSwipe)

Answer (score -2):

UINavigationControllerのナビゲーションバーは非表示にして、
UIView等で、ナビゲーションバーと同じようなUIにしてしまう方が楽だと思います。